# Check if JavaScript object was initialized already

Tags: javascript

Let's presume I have two JavaScript objects: **AjaxCalls** (the object used to handle, log, and eventually cache ajax calls made on my page), and **AjaxNavigator** (the object used to navigate on my page, without page refreshes).

**AjaxNavigator** is dependent on **AjaxCalls**, but not the other way around, **AjaxCalls** can be used by itself. When I create these objects when the page is ready, I do the following things:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   window.AjaxCalls=new AjaxCalls();
   window.AjaxNavigator=new AjaxNavigator();
});
```

When AjaxNavigator is created, it should check if AjaxCalls is defined already, if it is, it should store a reference to it in one of it's interior variables, and if not, it should define it inside one of it's interior variables. Is there any way to check if an AjaxCalls object was already initialized from inside AjaxNavigator?

```
function AjaxNavigator() {
  // check if any variable is an AjaxCalls object
}
```

Comment: `if(!(window.AjaxCalls instanceof AjaxCalls)) throw new Error('Window.AjaxCalls not defined')` ?

Comment: But what if I store AjaxCalls in a differently named variable? What if it is not me, who will be the end user of these objects, and I don't know in what named variable does AjaxCalls end?

Comment: You want to loop through everything? Seriously, when you are developing there should be some sort of coherent guideline or rule you are following so you can at least _assume_ the thing is in the right place.

Comment: If you cannot be sure where the `AjaxCalls` instance is located, then you will either have to have some search logic, or take control of instantiating another instance in a known location.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai: If you want to make the variable choosable, simply expect the `AjaxCalls` instance as a **parameter** to your `AjaxNavigator` constructor.

Comment: Btw, it's an incredibly bad idea to overwrite the variable in which the constructor function was stored with an instance.

Comment: Also, if both are dependent on each other and both are from your Ajax library, why aren't they included by default? And if your script is being included you might want to use Object.defineProperty to define the constructor and its instance as non-writeable so nobody can overwrite them and you are scott-free.